# Connecting to Movesense

Tags: ios

I have powered on the Movesense and built the iOS app and installed on my device. I refresh the device list, see a Movesense and tap to connect. From the Device tab in the app, I tap "Connect device", but the wheel spins but never seems to connect. Any ideas?

Other info that may indicate where the issue is: when tapping on the Logging tab and selecting Start data logging, I get the error "The operation couldn't be completed. ([wb] Failed to get resource error 404.) I see the same error when attempting to "Set device time" on the Time and HR tab.

[movesense](/questions/tagged/movesense)

Comment: There were problems with movesense-device-lib recently, but it's now updated. Can You try to build it with new sources? After the update I am able to connect via iOS.

Comment: It looks like the last update was 4/4? I tried to connect on 4/9, so should have gotten the latest version. Maybe I need to blast the directory and re-pull down the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an iOS BLE bug that manifested itself when we updated the device bluetooth stack to BLE 4.2 (Nordic Semiconductor SoftDevice 3.0.0). That combination caused the BLE connection getting stuck in service discovery phase.

The fix requires that you flash the latest Movesense device application to the sensor, not just the latest mobile app (actually just the sensor software update is needed because the fix/workaround is there).

So, please flash your sensor with the latest software and you should be able to connect just fine also with iPhone. If you are still having problems, please [make an issue](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/issues/new) in the bitbucket movesense-mobile-lib project.

*Full disclosure: I work for Movesense team*

Comment: What was the iOS bug?

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier, I didn't notice the comment. One description I found was this one:

https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/ANT-Shared-Channel-Demo/issues/1

The issue seems to be that the iOS sends MTU request and expects an swer, which in default implementation is not coming from nRF5 SDK 12.x. I'm not 100% sure whether this is iOS bug as such or something missing in SoftDevice BLE stack default handling. End result was that iOS would not do connect, while Android would have no problem.